# how to get json response in sequence

Tags: android, json

I need to get json object response in proper sequence as show in browser but it is random.
this is my Post function for get response from client.
I also want to get all Array field by iterator not by string like

jsonserch2.getString("@id");

I use Iterator myVeryOwnIterator=jsonserch2.keys() for fill iterator

```
String response = postData("http://url",generateRequestJson(this));


public static String postData(String url, String json) {
    final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    final ArrayList<NameValuePair> values = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    values.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", json));
    String response = "";
    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(values));
        final HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        response = convertInputStreamToString(httpResponse);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}

private static String convertInputStreamToString(HttpResponse response) {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        // JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new
        // InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        // Log.e("",""+reader);
        final StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        final String LineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        //

        //
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line + LineSeparator);
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (bufferedReader != null) {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: please paste your complete code here.

Comment: in browser it show sequence but when you get that from code then it is not in sequence but when you parse json then parse depend on your sequence then you get perfect data.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 public void getJsonData() {
      InputStream source = retrieveStream(url);     
      Gson gson = new Gson();      
      Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);      
      jsonPlots response = gson.fromJson(reader, jsonPlots.class);
      Toast.makeText(this, response.mFieldId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  // this works
    ArrayList<Plants> results = response.PlantArray;

}
```

Comment: is it not possible with json?